# When is the extension $\mathbb{Q}_p\left((-p)^{\frac{2}{n}} \right)$ totally ramified?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime number and consider the extensions $\mathbb{Q}_p\left((-p)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)$, $\mathbb{Q}_p\left((-p)^{\frac{2}{n}}\right)$ of the $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

- Are these fields two equal ?
- Are  they totally ramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ ?

---

The field $\mathbb{Q}_p\left((-p)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)$ is obtained by adding the roots of the polynomial $x^n+p$, which is Eisenstein and so it is totally ramified of degree $n$.

The field $\mathbb{Q}_p\left((-p)^{\frac{2}{n}}\right)$ is obtained by adding the roots of the polynomial $x^n+p^2$.

If $n$ is **even**, then we can write $x^n+p^2=(x^{n/2}+ip)(x^{n/2}-ip)$, where $i=\sqrt{-1} \in \mathbb{Q}_p$.

In other words, $\mathbb{Q}_p\left((-p)^{\frac{2}{n}}\right)=\mathbb{Q}_p\left((-p)^{\frac{1}{n/2}}\right)$.

So the field $\mathbb{Q}_p\left((-p)^{\frac{2}{n}}\right)$ is totally ramified of degree $n/2$.

So $\mathbb{Q}_p\left((-p)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p\left((-p)^{\frac{2}{n}}\right)$ both are totally ramified but $$\mathbb{Q}_p\left((-p)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right) \neq \mathbb{Q}_p\left((-p)^{\frac{2}{n}}\right).$$

Am I missing something for the case $n=$even ?

Thanks

Comment: Your first claim is incorrect if $n$ is composite, and your questions are strange.

Comment: 1) Prove that $\mathbb{Q}_p\left((-p)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)/\Bbb{Q}_p$ is totally ramified. 2)
 Any of its subextensions is totally ramified as well (trivial extension of residue field)

Comment: @reuns, thanks. The polynomial $x^n+p$ is Eisenstein at $p$, so the extension $\mathbb Q_p \left((-p)^{1/n} \right)$ is totally ramified. Therefore as a subextension $\mathbb Q_p \left((-p)^{2/n} \right)$ is also totally ramified. Is it ?

Comment: For general $n$, the notation $\mathbb Q_p((-p)^{1/n})$ is not good to start with, because not all roots of the polynomial $x^n+p$ lie in the same unique field extension of $\mathbb Q_p$. And the field one gets from adjoining *all* roots of that polynomial, i.e. the splitting field, has degree larger than $n$.